# In the US, are inside loops permitted while flying a US- registered DG-1000S sailplane in the "utility" category?

Tags: faa-regulations, aerobatics

Are inside loops are permitted while flying a US-registered DG-1000S sailplane in the US in the utility category?

FAR 91.1 seems highly relevant:

> §91.9   Civil aircraft flight manual, marking, and placard
>   requirements.
>
> (a) Except as provided in paragraph (d) of this section, no person may
>   operate a civil aircraft without complying with the operating
>   limitations specified in the approved Airplane or Rotorcraft Flight
>   Manual, markings, and placards, or as otherwise prescribed by the
>   certificating authority of the country of registry.

More information: the English version of the factory-produced flight manual for the German-made DG-1000S glider ([may be downloaded here](http://adelaidesoaring.on.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/DG-1000s-Flight-Manual.pdf)) states the following--

> 2.6 Approved manoeuvres Category „Utility“: The glider is certified for normal gliding in the "Utility" category. Simple aerobatics are
>   approved but only without waterballast and with the weight of the rear
>   pilot compensated by ballast in the ballast box in the fin see section
>   6.8.7.
>
> The following aerobatic manoeuvres are approved with all spans:
>
> Spins
>
> Chandelle
>
> Inside loop
>
> Turn
>
> Lazy Eight
>
> Recommended entry speeds see section 4.5.8.1.

The manual then goes on to describe additional maneuvers allowed when flown at a lower weight limit, in the "aerobatic" category:

> In addition to the manoeuvres in category „Utility“ the following manoeuvres are approved:
>
> Inverted flight
>
> half flick roll from normal to inverted flight with half loop
>
> half loop and half roll
>
> half flick roll from inverted to normal flight
>
> half roll and half loop
>
> slow roll

Before answering, you may wish to  consider the significance of the last quoted phrase in FAR 91.9, "or as otherwise prescribed by the certificating authority of the country of registry".  A "yes" answer to the basic question implies that this phrase in FAR 91.9 does not somehow prohibit looping a US-registered example of this glider in the US.

Comment: This question is a pared-down version of a broader multi-part question that is receiving few answers: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/66531/in-the-us-would-it-ever-be-legal-to-fly-a-loop-in-any-airplane-or-glider-that-w

Answer (score 1):

Stuff you quoted in your question seems to provide the answer you're after:

> 2.6 Approved manoeuvres Category „Utility“: The glider is certified for normal gliding in the "Utility" category. Simple aerobatics are approved but only without waterballast and with the weight of the rear pilot compensated by ballast in the ballast box in the fin see section 6.8.7.
>
> The following aerobatic manoeuvres are approved with all spans:
>
> ...
>
> Inside loop

Comment: I think you are right- just wondered whether any problem was caused by that last quoted phrase in FAR 91.9, "or as otherwise prescribed by the certificating authority of the country of registry".

Comment: I'm assuming that the "certificating authority of the country of registry" would mean the FAA- do they even officially approve the flight manuals, placards, etc of an aircraft certified in another country?

Comment: I'm not familiar with other countries, I've only flown in the US and the Bahamas. Might fly in Canada sometime, need to apply for international use radio license, any maybe do something for 121.5 MHz ELT as I have updated to 406 MHz GPS ELT.